# methods which are invoked automatically when a tab is selected in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nstabview

I have a tabview in which i have added 3 tabview Items.In each tab i have fields into which i want to populate data automatically. Which methods are invoked automatically when a tab is clicked.Please help me in this...

Answer (score 4):

`NSTabView` allows you to specify an object as its delegate. This delegate object should be an instance of a class that conforms to the `NSTabViewDelegate` protocol. This protocol declares, amongst others methods,

- `-tabView:willSelectTabViewItem:` to inform the delegate that a tab item is about to be selected;
- `-tabView:didSelectTabViewItem:` to inform the delegate that a tab item has been selected.

You probably want to implement `-tabView:willSelectTabViewItem:` so that the fields are populated right before that tab item is selected.

Comment: i have created NSViewController sub classes for each tab, the tabview is created on a NSWindowController class. Where should i write these methods. I tried writting this methods in ViewController subclass. if any bindings are needed please tell me how to do that.

Comment: @kiran If you’ve created that tab view in a subclass of `NSWindowController`, make that subclass conform to `NSTabViewDelegate` and implement the delegate method(s) there. Your instance of that subclass of `NSWindowController` must be set as the delegate of the tab view, either in Interface Builder or in code.

Comment: Thanks a ton to u, it is working. Give me your mail id am working on some project i surely need ur guidance and help.

Comment: @kiran When you have other programming-related questions, post them on this site.